# Can "candidate" be used as a verb?

Tags: single-word-requests

I see on some sites that "candidate" is used as a verb.
Example:

> I am candidating for this position.

But I find it only listed as a noun by [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/candidate) and [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/candidate).

Can this word be used as a verb?

Comment: What a horrible usage! What's wrong with "I am a candidate for this position"?

Comment: @Mari-LouA probably because they didn't say where they saw it.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The full close reason is lack of research or the question is better suited to ELL. Maybe the close votes were for the second half.

Comment: There's no noun that can't be verbed

Comment: @BlueWhale "Verbing weirds language" - Calvin

Comment: @DavidRicherby EL&U users already have the option to migrate posts to ELL. By selecting the lack of research, a close-voter is suggesting the OP is unable to find help online, so perhaps they should try our sister-site. The implied message being  that native or highly competent speakers easily know the answer to the language question.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm so used to SE sites with no useful migration paths that I didn't even look at the migration options here. So I don't think you can assume that people who vote for a close reason that explictly mentions ELL did so knowing that voting to migrate there was an option.

Comment: @DavidRicherby users who are familiar with close voting posts, and there's a fair number of core users who spend each and every day day closing off-topic questions, know which option they are selecting.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thank you for fixing that. I had to add "correctly" to get over the edit limit.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, the noun *candidate* can be used as a verb. ***[Verbing](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/verbing)*** nouns is very common in English. However, in a very formal setting such as a job application, I would avoid it. Instead,  I'd suggest the following solution:

> "I **am applying for** the position of *blah, blah, blah*"

1. The important thing is to understand that the interviewer must understand the candidate's personality and if he/she is fit for the position where he is **candidated**. [source](https://www.glassdoor.co.nz/Interview/Salesforce-Paris-Interview-Questions-EI_IE11159.0,10_IL.11,16_IC2881970.htm)
2. Maybe **he's candidating** for the UCA ministry? [source](https://www.trendsmap.com/twitter/tweet/1058998011013951488)
3. Like a number of human politicians, such as the Queensland Premier, Loupi lives outside the electorate **he's candidating** for. If you want to know more about him, ... [source](http://www.mrbumpycat.com/2013/02/introducing-candidate-for-lingiari.html)
4. I think she should be on the ballot and I would vote for her no matter what **she was candidating** for. She is brilliant, has a kindness about her ... [source](https://bentonquesthouse.com/2016/10/)
5. The contest is open to all artists regardless of age, sex, nationality or artistic curriculum and can participate with no more than 3 works; they **can be candidated** even in different sections. [source](https://www.canovaprize.com/privacy)

Comment: Yes, the noun candidate can be used as a verb. -- but that does not mean it should be.

Comment: I think the political examples (where someone is running for office) could use _campaigning_ rather than _applying for_.

Comment: @jsw29  I'd like to point out that (5) has been deleted, I was out all day yesterday and waited until I was home before fixing it. Thank you to everyone who pointed out the mistake, it looked like a sentence using "going to" with a future meaning but instead I totally glossed over the possessive marker *Joe Biden's* in "going to candidate Joe Biden's Cedar Rapids"

Answer (score 9):

The OED lists this as

> **candidate**, *v.* 2
>
> *U.S. colloquial.*
>   To stand as a candidate.
>
> - 1848   *J. R. Lowell Biglow Papers 1st ser. viii. 122*   The can'idatin' line, you know, 'ould suit me to a T... So I'll set up ez can'idate fer any kin' o' office.
> - 1884   *Cent. Mag. June 308/1*   Let him put the question to some [choir-singers] who every spring have to candidate for a situation.
> - 1909   *Springfield (Mass.) Weekly Republican 2 Sept. 14*   Mr. Seccombe candidated in the Goschen church last spring.

Not being in the U.S. myself, I'd look at you oddly if you said you were "canditating for this position".

While there is a tradition of ["verbification"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbification), it's not advised to coin a new verb yourself in formal speech, especially if an appropriate verb -- in your case **applying** -- is available. Unmoderated verbing weirds language.

Comment: In the present day, however, I would say *candidating* is mainly jocular, except in the jargon of Baptist and Congregationalist churches.

Comment: @choster [Mari-Lou managed to find numerous modern examples](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/504811/30894)

Comment: I upvoted because of the OED reference but the OP was questioning whether the form was legitimate or possible having seen instances of this usage in the wild.

Comment: As an American, I would find this odd as well. Maybe it's used as jargon in some subcultures, but it's probably not a great idea to just throw it into a sentence apropos of nothing.

Answer (score 2):

**[Candidate](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/candidate)** (Dictionary.com)

> verb (used without object)  can·di·dat·ed, can·di·dat·ing.
>
> to become a candidate for service as a new minister of a church; preach
>  before a congregation that is seeking
>  a new minister.

Answer (score 1):

As a BE speaker, novel verbing of a noun makes the speaker sound like they are speaking AmE. If it's common to create new terms, it's in American English rather than British English. I guess what I am saying is it's probably more acceptable to citizens of the US than to those of the UK. In the UK many of them grate and most such usages should be avoided. There are some examples in BE (for instance abusing the name of a maker of vaccum cleaners, most BE speakers would not find 'hoovering' at all out of place, whereas the verbing of 'medal' as in 'Usaine Bolt is medalling' is something only a few sports commentators use in BE) but fewer than AmE.

Comment: I'm a bit skeptical of this claim. I'm not saying you're wrong, but (1) there's a long history of British speakers perceiving usages as "Americanisms" that are no such thing; (2) just because you hear an American say something that sounds strange to you, that doesn't mean that all Americans would find it normal and all Brits would find it strange; and (3) you would never notice if there's a verbing that you use and Americans don't.

Comment: (For the specific example of *candidating*, by the way, I find it just as strange as you do. I'm not even sure how to pronounce it; "candidate-ing" is really hard to say, but "candi-dating" seems obviously wrong.)

Comment: @ruakh I would certainly say "candi-dating", but then I also say "candi-date".

Comment: @ruakh I think it's that verbing nouns like this is quite common in business-speak which, in turn, is perceived as being American, for whatever reason.

Comment: This verb may be imported from native speakers of German, where there is the verb *kandidieren*.